# css grid is not working in one page but working at other page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a Portfolio application but on my home page the grid is not working and all of my different div tags are overlapping on each other

[image]

But it is working on my portfolio page

*Code*:-
JS Part

```js
function HomePG(){
    return(
        <div className="homePGMain">
            <div className="BGpant">
                <div className="TopHead">
                    <h1>
                            Hi There,<br/>
                            Sukarna Jana<br/>
                            /* kept repeating */
                            ...
                            ...
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="demo">
                <h1>
                    Hi There,<br/>
                    Sukarna Jana<br/>
                    /* kept repeating */
                        ...
                        ...
                </h1>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

CSS Part

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.homePGMain{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-row-gap: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
}
.BGpant{
    display:grid;
    display: flex;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 255, 255) , rgb(71, 38, 255));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
// ... ///
.demo{
    display:grid;
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
}
```

*The Whole code is there on [Github](https://github.com/Sukarnascience/MyPortfolio)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.BGpant` and `.demo`. They're overlapping because they're both absolute positioned siblings. Their parent uses `display: grid;`, but they're not being laid out by the grid because of their absolute positions.